# Logstash removing prefix from xml message

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using logstash to ingest xml messages via the xml filter plugin. Consider the following xml example:

```
<fruit.producer1:Apple>
    ...
</fruit.producer1:Apple>
<fruit.producer2:Apple>
    ...
</fruit.producer2:Apple>
```

My filter configuration is as follows:

```
filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
        force_array => false
        target => "fruit"
    }
}
```

The result after the filter which is sent to elasticsearch is:

```
...
"Apple": {
    ...
},
"Apple": {
    ...
}
...
```

As you can see, I have no way of distinguishing between `Apple` from `producer1` or `producer2`. I have played with the remove_namespaces setting in the filter configuration, but nothing seems to work. How can I ensure that the prefix information is preserved in the output to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not like `.` or `:` in field names. Solution was to use `gsub` on raw message before xml filter.

```
filter {
    mutate {
        gsub => [
            "message", "fruit.producer1:Apple", "fruit_producer1_Apple",
            "message", "fruit.producer2:Apple", "fruit_producer2_Apple"
       ]
    }

    xml {
        source => "message"
        force_array => false
        target => "fruit"
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
"fruit": {
    "fruit_producer1_Apple": {
        ...
    },
    "fruit_producer2_Apple": {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Elasticsearch 2.0, dots were not allowed in field names. Probably that is reason xml filter might have been coded this way. You may try to add another filter to change dots to underscore or something else. A ruby filter should help as available here- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/field-name-cannot-contain/33251/38

Comment: Thanks for your response. I went back and had a look at my real data, and noticed the sample I included in my post was not representative as it also contains a colon. You could be right in that characters like these are not allowed in field names. I will go back and test and see how it goes.

Comment: I have successfully tested this now and can confirm that elasticsearch does not like `.` and and `:` in field names. I worked around this with the [gsub mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub).

Comment: Doesn't gsub is applied for field value and not for field name. May be you should add your solution also here.

Comment: If you do it on the raw message before the xml filter, it works. Solution below...